# Submeter um post com reload de apenas de uma div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, zend

Tenho um form que desejo passar via POST, mas sem dar reload na página inteira, após o envio das informações, desejava que uma div desse reload no seu conteúdo, tenho o seguinte código:

```
<script>
        $(function()
        {
            $("#issuedButton, #expiredButton, #activeButton, #revokedButton").click(function(){
                var dataString = $("#searchByTime").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "index",
                    data: dataString
                });
                $("#reload").load("index #reload");
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

O POST está sendo enviado, porém, não sei se o reload não está sendo feito, ou está sendo feito sem atualizar as informações com dados recebidos via POST. Segue a div:

```
<div id="reload">
    <?php var_dump($this->searchbyorganization); ?>
</div>
```

Está em um var dump apenas para debug. Utilizo do Zend Framework, então a lógica está em outra classe controladora.

Comment: Acredito q vc deva usar o *done* ou um *success* do AJAX para obter o resultado do post

Comment: Assim como você não fará um "reload" da div, você deverá reescrever seu conteúdo com o retorno do post ajax ou fazer uma nova requisição ajax depois da success de seu post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim como indicado nos comentários não faça `load`, ao invés disso implemente o *handler* de sucesso com `done` ou `success` e nesse *handler* atualize o *html* da `<div>` que interessa.

Exemplo:

```
$("#issuedButton, #expiredButton, #activeButton, #revokedButton").click(function(){
    var dataString = $("#searchByTime").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index",
        data: dataString
    }).done(function(dados){ //done em vez de load
        $("#reload").html(dados); //atribuir o conteúdo do div com a função html()
    });

    return false;
});
```

Note que estou a assumir que os dados enviados da página `php` já são o *html* atualizado a substituir no conteúdo da `<div id="reload">`

Comment: Então, ele carregou o html inteiro da página dentro da div, o que eu queria, é que ele só desse um refresh na div, como acontece num submit.

Comment: @ViniciusMacelai A minha resposta funciona dessa forma. O ajax é assincrono e não força refresh, e não é feita a navegação no submit do formulário devido ao `return false;`. Depois o `$("#reload").html(dados)` recarrega apenas o div que quer

Comment: acho que entendi o que aconteceu, na variavel "dados" está toda página HTML, apenas mudei para isso $("#reload").html($(dados).find("#reload")); e funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda.